# Is there a way to create a sequence column that automatically reset?

Tags: ms-access

Say we have 1 table:

```
ReferenceCode   PartyCode   CreateDate  WorkType    OtherInfo   SubTask AnalystName ID
30697504D   4310600358  07/07/2020  BM_UBE  4310600358  ab  john    18
30697504D   4310600358  07/07/2020  BM_UBE  4310600358  ab  james   18
30913460D   5242222418  07/07/2020  BM_ACM  5242222418  123 john    20
30913460D   5242222418  07/07/2020  BM_ACM  5242222418  123 james   20
30864396D   3116638557  07/06/2020  BM_MTE  3116638557  q   john    16
30864396D   3116638557  07/06/2020  BM_MTE  3116638557  q   james   16
30894467D   QB13198190  07/06/2020  BM_MTE  QB13198190  q   john    17
30894467D   QB13198190  07/06/2020  BM_MTE  QB13198190  q   james   17
30912706D   QB12446351  07/07/2020  BM_MMO  QB12446351  q   john    19
30912706D   QB12446351  07/07/2020  BM_MMO  QB12446351  q   james   19
30912706D   QB12446351  07/07/2020  BM_MMO  QB12446351  q   peter   19
```

And I need an output like this:

```
ReferenceCode   PartyCode   CreateDate  WorkType    OtherInfo   SubTask AnalystName ID  Sequence
30697504D   4310600358  07/07/2020  BM_UBE  4310600358  ab  john    18  1
30697504D   4310600358  07/07/2020  BM_UBE  4310600358  ab  james   18  2
30913460D   5242222418  07/07/2020  BM_ACM  5242222418  123 john    20  1
30913460D   5242222418  07/07/2020  BM_ACM  5242222418  123 james   20  2
30864396D   3116638557  07/06/2020  BM_MTE  3116638557  q   john    16  1
30864396D   3116638557  07/06/2020  BM_MTE  3116638557  q   james   16  2
30894467D   QB13198190  07/06/2020  BM_MTE  QB13198190  q   john    17  1
30894467D   QB13198190  07/06/2020  BM_MTE  QB13198190  q   james   17  2
30912706D   QB12446351  07/07/2020  BM_MMO  QB12446351  q   john    19  1
30912706D   QB12446351  07/07/2020  BM_MMO  QB12446351  q   james   19  2
30912706D   QB12446351  07/07/2020  BM_MMO  QB12446351  q   peter   19  3
```

As you can see, the `Sequence column` resets for every group of `ID`. How do you do this in MS Access using sql query?

EDIT:
All columns on table 1 are identical except `AnalystName` and `ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what already mentioned to @June7 answer you need a unique identifier (You can use a `AutoNumber` field). I have used `AutoID` column as `AutoNumber` datatype and then use below query-

```
SELECT t.*, (SELECT Count(*)
            from MyTable as t2
            WHERE (t2.AutoID <= t.AutoID And t2.ID = t.ID)
            ) AS Sequence
FROM MyTable AS t;
```

***Output screenshot:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work with the help of @June7:

```
SELECT 
A.ID, 
A.AnalystName,
A.ReferenceCode, 
A.PartyCode, 
A.CreateDate, 
A.WorkType, 
A.OtherInfo, 
A.SubTask,
Count(B.ID) + 1 AS [Sequence],
A.ItemCount
FROM 
vPriorityCaseB AS A
LEFT JOIN
vPriorityCaseB AS B
ON
(
A.ReferenceCode = B.ReferenceCode
OR
(A.ReferenceCode IS NULL AND B.ReferenceCode IS NULL)
)
AND
A.PartyCode = B.PartyCode
AND
A.CreateDate = B.CreateDate
AND
A.WorkType = B.WorkType
AND
(
A.OtherInfo = B.OtherInfo
OR
(A.OtherInfo IS NULL AND B.OtherInfo IS NULL)
)
AND
(
A.SubTask = B.SubTask
OR 
(A.SubTask IS NULL AND B.SubTask IS NULL)
)
AND
A.Counter > B.Counter
GROUP BY 
A.ID, 
A.AnalystName,
A.ReferenceCode, 
A.PartyCode, 
A.CreateDate, 
A.WorkType, 
A.OtherInfo, 
A.SubTask,
A.ItemCount
```

Where Counter is my AutoNumber. Had to do it this way since using sub query gets really slow when working with huge amount of data.